# Returning min in list of lists error

Tags: function

Trying to return the min value in this function, but I keep getting the error "TypeError: my_min() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given." Advice on what I need to change?

```
def my_min(xss):
    min = xss[0] 
    for i in xss:
        if i < min:
            min = i
    return min
```

Comment: your method is defined to take just one argument: `xss`, yet when calling it you are passing three: `[2, 3], [], [4, 1, -5]`. Your title said list-of-list, so you probably want to pass `[[2, 3], [], [4, 1, -5]]`

Comment: a/ what is sequence in `for i in sequence:`? b/ what result do you expect from that call, exactly?

Comment: Typo, it was supposed to be the list xss.

Comment: For example if my_min_([[2,3],[4,1,5]]), the least value would be 1. I ran it with the code with still the same error with no return value of 1.

Comment: The implementation of your `my_min` function doesn't work at all for nested lists. Why do you expect it to handle anything but one list?

Comment: Is there another method to increment through each nested list to find the min of all of them or do I have to change the lists entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your first problem is that you were calling your method with three lists when you should be calling it as a list-of-lists. To be more explicit, you should be calling as:

```
my_min([[2,3],[],[4,1,-5]])
```

Now, the next problem you are facing is that you are only iterating through the first level of your list. This is incorrect. You have to realize you have a list of lists. So, to stick to the logic in your solution, you need to iterate again inside your for loop to find the minimum value of each list inside your list. Your `min_val` (I changed the name because it shadows the built-in `min`)

```
def my_min(xss):
    min_val = None
    # iterate over the first loop
    for i in xss:
        # i now is each sublist in your list
        for j in i:
            if min_val is None or j < min_val:
                min_val = j
    return min_val

print(my_min([[], [2,3],[],[4,1,-5]]))
```

result -> `-5`

Per the comment by Blckknght, you can actually still pass three separate lists to your method, by declaring with an `*`, which is an unpacking argument in this case. So:

```
def my_min(*xss)
```

If you pass your separate lists like you originally were, it will work, and you will end up with a tuple of lists. The solution will not change, it just adds the ability to pass to your method the way you were originally doing it. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) is the doc on argument unpacking.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I was confused with the varying levels of iteration and assumed it applied to all levels.

Comment: The initialization of `min_val` will break if the first inner list is empty (rather than one of the later ones, as it is in the example). You could initialize to `None` then change `if j < min_val` to `if j is None or j < min_val`. I'd also suggest that `def my_min(*xss)` would be a different fix to the issue of multiple lists as separate arguments.

Comment: @Blckknght Really appreciate the review on my answer. Silly I missed that case =/. I fixed it, and it should handle that case now. And good call on the unpacking. I added that as an explanation to the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the content within another list as `[[2,3],[],[4,1,-5]]`. Hence your function call should be:

```
my_min([[2,3],[],[4,1,-5]])
```

You are getting this error because without wrapping these to the `list`, these are getting treated as three separate argument to the function. But your function is defined to accept just one.

Simplest way to find the minimum in number in the list of lists is using `min` function as:

```
def my_min(xss):
    return min([min(item) for item in xss if item])
```

Comment: For example if my_min_([[2,3],[4,1,5]]), the least value would be 1. I ran it with the code with still the same error with no return value of 1.

Comment: @AlanWakke: Made an edit. Sample function is mentioned the end of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes only a single argument, you can use multiple arguments by commas

```
my_min(a,b,c) #takes 3 arguments instead of one
```

Or just call the function multiple times if you want to test the function for different test cases

```
my_min([2,3])
my_min([])
my_min([4,1,-5])
```

You can also use lists within lists if you are looking to do that

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other, the first thing to do is to pass my_min a list by wrapping your input like this:

```
my_min([[2,3],[],[4,1,-5]])
```

Then, what you need to do is find the min recursively. I have also added a check for an empty list

```
from math import inf

def my_min(xss):
    if not xss:
        return inf
    min = inf
    for i in xss:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            i = my_min(i)
        if i < min:
            min = i
    return min

my_min([[2,3],[],[4,1,-5]])
```